# Use cases of the argument feed_dict of the method Session.run

Tags: tensorflow

In the [TensorFlow's documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run) regarding the `feed_dict` argument of the `Session.run` method, we have

> The optional `feed_dict` argument allows the caller to override the value of tensors in the graph.

or

> `feed_dict`: A dictionary that maps *graph elements* to values (described above).

Which graph elements? All of them?

I understood I can use `feed_dict` to feed placeholders, but is there any other use case? If not, why not explicitly emphasizing the fact that `feed_dict` is used only to feed placeholders? If yes, which ones? I would appreciate examples.

Comment: Even in this lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PicxU81owCs&feature=youtu.be&t=1192 the answer was that the `feed_dict` is used *just* to feed the `tf.placeholder`. I haven't seen any other use case in code other than feeding some inputs to the network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`feed_dict` can be used to feed *any* tensors in the graph. In practice it is convenient to make tensors that have to be fed, `Placeholder` nodes, since an error will be thrown if they aren't fed. But, say you are debugging a graph, you can feed add fetch any intermediate tensors in the graph.

Here is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    a = tf.constant(1, name="a")
    b = tf.constant(2, name="b")
    c = tf.add(a, b, name="c")

    # prints 3
    print(sess.run(c)) 

    # prints 4 since we have fed a new value for a, for just this run.
    print(sess.run(c, feed_dict={a:2}))
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: You're using the name of the constant as the key to the `feed_dict`. Is there any particular reason why you're not using the Python object `a`? I am asking this because I think I read around that there are some restrictions regarding which objects the keys of `feed_dict` can be.